# Парсинг группы ВК

Tags: simple-html-dom, php, синтаксический-анализ, vkontakte-api, javascript

Задача такая - нужно парсить последние три записи со стены из определенной группы вконтакте.

Можно ли это сделать с помощью VK Api без авторизации пользователей?

Если ли более гуманные методы, чем дергать страничку с помощью PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser?

Интересуют решения на js / php / rails.

Answer (score 1):

https://vk.com/dev/wall.get - *Это открытый метод, не требующий* **access token** ( значит можно писать запрос типа http://api.vk.com/method/wall.get?owner_id=-GROUP_ID&count=3 )
В чём проблема то?

Comment: Проблема в том что при инициализации с помощью Open API для пользователей, которые не авторизованы ВК api не работает.

Если забирать просто ajax'ом, то ругается на кроссдоменные права доступа. JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y9BAb/ 

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.vk.com/method/photos.get?owner_id=1&album_id=136592355&count=100&rev=1. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access.